# Django Rest Framework: obtain user details and permissions with token login

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

My (Angular) frontend performs jwt login to the Django Rest Framework backend through the provided `jwt_views.TokenObtainPairView` class.

However, this returns only access and refresh tokens, and I'd actually like to get more, such as username and the permissions the user has (so that the frontend can hide or disable any features the user can't use anyway).

What would be the best solution to achieve this?

- Write my own token-generating view?
- Subclass the existing view and overwrite the serializer with one that fetches user information?
- Use a different method to transfer permissions or to log in?

The level of 'magic' that happens in Django confuses me as to what parameters and values I can set and overwrite.

Comment: What package are you using?

Comment: `rest_framework_simplejwt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to subclass **`TokenObtainPairView`** as well as **`TokenObtainPairSerializer`**.

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView


class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    def validate(self, attrs):
        attrs = super().validate(attrs)
        return {
            "username": self.user.username,
            "email": self.user.email,
            "permissions": self.user.user_permissions.values_list("codename", flat=True),
            "groups": self.user.groups.values_list("name", flat=True),
            **attrs,
        }


class MyTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = MyTokenObtainPairSerializer
```

You can access the authenticated user in the serializer by calling **`self.user`** and hence you can access their permissions by **`self.user.user_permissions.all()`**

Also, do not forget to connect your *new view class* to the `urls.py`

Comment: this works fine. Perhaps a follow-up question since I cannot seem to find best-practice info on it. Would you generally let the frontend check against permission/group information to decide which features to show?

Comment: I would choose that way.